# vim: how to customize context sensitive autocomplete?

Tags: vim

For example, for any file that ends in `.foo`, I would like the following behavior in vim:

- if the user types `i.`, I want vim's autocomplete to provide the list `dogs, cats, mice`
- if the user types `i.dogs.`, I want vim's autocomplete to provide the list `poodle,dachshund,pitbull`

fwiw, I need to use this functionality in a customized language for easy typing/learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom insert-mode completion via `'omnifunc'` or `'completefunc'`. Read up on the details at `:help complete-functions`; there are also examples.

Vim uses filetypes (e.g. `java`, `c`, `markdown`) as a abstraction over file extensions, which are only one way to represent the type of file (others are e.g. the `#!/bin/bash` hashbang lines at the top of an executable script). You can write a custom filetype detection, like this:

```
:autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.foo setf foo
```

And then put your custom completion in `~/.vim/ftplugin/foo_completion.vim` with contents like this:

```
:setlocal completefunc=FooCompletion
```

I hope these pointers help; please refer to the help and existing filetypes for the details.